# SDE possibly related to Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Say we have $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are stochastic processes and $f$ is a differentiable function.

If we have:

> $\displaystyle dX_t = (rdt+adB_t)X_t,\text{ where } B_t$ is (standard) Brownian motion

then we end up with Geometric Brownian motion.

I want to consider the following:

> $\displaystyle dX_t = -f(X_t)Y_t(dt+dB_t)$

and let us assume $Y_t$ is a process driven by Brownian motion.

Can this be solved for in a similar way as the Geometric Brownian motion case?

Comment: these are not SDE...

Comment: @Surb yes correct, I used incorrect notation, I have edited to put in correct notation of what I meant.